# Using #define in a while loop

Tags: c, loops, c-preprocessor

I'm learning how to program in **C**, but I can't figure out how to loop using a constant. Its my understanding that the best way to use a constant value in **C** is through the `#define` statement (correct me if I'm wrong). But it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM = 3

void main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int i=0;

  while(i<NUM){
    printf("foo ");
    i++;
  }

  return;
 }
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following error.

> helloWorld.c: In function ‘main’:
>       helloWorld.c:9: error: expected expression before ‘=’ token

(For those of you who don't want to count, line 9 is the while loop declaration).
How can I do this using preprocessor functions, and is that the best way to use constant values in C? I can get it to work using 'const' but I don't think thats best.

Comment: -1 for 1 upvote for this question....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `#define` to declare a *macro*, which you can kind of think of as a type of constant in some cases.

Actually, what happens is the compiler replaces any occurrences of your macro with your macro text. In your case, `= 3`. This results in `while(i < = 3)`, which is a syntax error.

The correct way to write the macro is:

```
#define NUM 3
```

To define a real constant, use the `const` keyword.

Comment: I like to read `const` as "readonly": `const` is not really a real constant :)

Answer (score 7):

use

`#define NUM  3` intead of `#define NUM = 3`

Answer (score 1):

**#define NUM = 3**
use

**#define NUM 3**

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use your compilers pre-process only option so you can solve these problems
yourself.

E.G.

```
% gcc -E foo.c > bar.c
```

You find line 9 using offsets from the line directive macros in bar.c, but it shows clearly
your error:

```
while(i< = 3){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NUM = 3
```

should be

```
#define NUM 3
```

Comment: +1 for a true statement, but -1 for not explaining why this doesn't expand into `while (i <= 3)`, incorrect but compilable.